# What is the better choice: A wide neural network or a deep neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I am really new to deep learning, I wonder that if we build a wide NN which has just only one hidden layer but it has much more units than a NN which has more hidden layers but has less units on hidden layers than the other one.

What is the NN which will give us the best performance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, deep NNs will generalize better, hence most cutting edge networks go deeper and not wider, which at some point introduces problems as well. The optimal solution depends on your problem though. You can find a detailed answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223637/247890).